# custom search with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoose

I am building search algorithm with mongoose, and i now need to do string similarity, since regex does not satisfy my needs i would like to use custom algorithm for string searching, i saw a pretty good and popular [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity) and i would like to use it while searching, for example, searching similar description. is it possible to use it in this context?

```
Model.find({
    description: //search here
});
```

Comment: Not possible. Take a look https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid_fulltext

Comment: so it is impossible to perform manual operations while querying? only thing i can do is to manipulate result?

Comment: Exactly, MongoDb doesn't allow fuzzy search... Also take a look ElasticSearch, which is best suited for your use case

Comment: Well, as i saw it is whole another DB and i am not up to migrate to another databae :(

Comment: [Text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#text-search) in MongoDB does language-based word stemming and diacritics.  Would that help your use case?

Comment: well, text search would not help me since it is language based